# How to free memory allocated in a function without returning its pointer?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a function like this:

```
int fun(){
    int* arr = new int[10];
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        arr[i] = 5;
    }
    delete[] arr;  // 
    return arr[6];
}

int main(){
    std::cout << fun();
    return 0;
}
```

What am i going to do is to free the memory whick is pointed to by the pointer `arr`. But the function is not returning pointer `arr`. So i tryed to free it inside the function.
It won't print anything if  `delete[] arr` is above `return arr[6]` (Using Visual Studio 2019).
But if `return arr[6]` is above `delete[] arr` , would the memory be freed or this sentence be skipped?
Or should i declare `arr` inside `main()` then free it in `main()`?

Comment: In short: You cannot. But the good news is, you don't need `new` and `delete` for your use case at all, a simple `int arr[] {0};` would work fine for your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless it's for academic purposes, you rarely see a C++ program using manual memory allocation, you don't need to do it since you have a set of containers in the [STL containers library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) that do this memory management reliably for you. In your particular example, a [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is recommended.

That said, to answer your question:

> *It won't print anything if `delete[] arr` is above return `arr[6]` (Using Visual Studio 2019).*

If you delete the array before accessing the data stored in it the behavior is undefined. It's only natural that it doesn't print anything. [It could also print the expected result](https://godbolt.org/z/n6W3hrMYf), that's one of the *features* of [undefined behavior](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/intro.defs#defns.undefined). Using Visual Studio or not, it's the same.

> *But if return `arr[6]` is above `delete[] arr`, would the memory be freed or this sentence be skipped?*

Yes it would be skipped, or more accurately, all code after the return statement will not be executed. The memory will not be freed.

> *Or should I declare `arr` inside `main()` then free it in `main()`?*

If the data should belong in the `main`'s scope you should definitely declare it there, you can pass it to the function as an argument:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

int fun(int* arr) {
    assert(arr);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        arr[i] = 5;
    }
    return arr[6];
}

int main() {
    int* arr = new int[10];
    std::cout << fun(arr);
    delete[] arr;
    return 0;
}
```